# Website / App sizes

Tags: python, django, shared-hosting, virtualhost

What would you consider a micro, small, medium and large site based on unique visitors etc.

Assuming all sites are very basic like: Django, blogging, photo uploading, etc.

No special apps doing any crazy processing, just normal business website.

Im trying to figure out how many Django sites would be comfortable on a Linode 512 or similar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Micro <= 1k unique visitors/month and <= 5k pageviews
- Small = 5k unique visitors/month and = 25k pageviews
- Medium = 25k unique visitors/month and = 150k pageviews
- Large >= 200k unique visitors/month and >= 1M - 1.5M pageviews

It is hard to tell how many users you will fit on your Django site, because we have no idea what IO throughput you are expecting and how the read vs. write ratio looks like. If you are building a standard webapp, where for every write that occurs by a user there will be a 1000 reads, you will be able to fit comfortable one medium site (see above definitions) on the Linode 512MB box under the condition that you cache the dynamically generated HTML (memcache is great) and that you put all truly static content in a CDN (CloudFiles from Rackspace is awesome).

Hope this helps.
M.

[Cloudfiles (CDN) from Rackspace and Akamain](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/files/)

[Rackspace Cloud Servers, Linode 512MB equivalent for 21 bucks a month](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/pricing/)

[MemCache is awesome for distributed caching](http://memcached.org/)